# File Systems: Change commit interval while file system is mounted?

Tags: linux, filesystems, root-filesystem

is it possible - and if yes, how - to change the commit interval of a mounted file system while the file system is mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out - reading the manual helps...

The mount commant has a "remount" option that tries to change mount options of already mounted file systems.

See man mount(8):

> remount
>
> Attempt to remount an already-mounted filesystem.  This is
>   commonly used to change the mount flags for a  filesystem,  especially
>   to make a readonly filesystem writable.  It does not change device or
>   mount point.